# How to understand a mysterious method to calculate the Centroid of a Quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, centroid

We are trying to find the centroid of a quadrilateral by using a method that is different from [Wiki: Centroid of a polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon). 
For a convex (maybe applicable for an arbitrary) 3D quadrilateral has the vertices $V^0_i=[X^0_i,Y^0_i,Z^0_i]$, $i=1\dots4$, in a global frame. In numerical analysis, it is more convenient to work on a local coordinate system for each element and in a simplified 2D region.
First we take the averaged point $O^0=[X_o,Y_o,Z_o]$ as the temporary origin of the local frame
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}X_o\\Y_o\\ Z_o\end{bmatrix}=&\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^4\begin{bmatrix}X^0_i\\Y^0_i\\Z^0_i\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
The vertices of the quadrilateral relative to point $O^0$ become $V_i=[X^0_i-X_o,Y^0_i-Y_o,Z^0_i-Z_o]$, $i=1\dots4$.
Next we can find the local coordinates of the vertices through a standard transformation. Let us build a right-handed set of axes $tsn-$ (local system) as follows: assume a unit vector $\vec t$ is obtained from the bimedian vector of sides $\overrightarrow{V^0_3V^0_4}$ and $\overrightarrow{V^0_1V^0_2}$, the unit normal vector of the quadrilateral plane from $\vec n=\overrightarrow{V^0_2V^0_4}\times\overrightarrow{V^0_1V^0_3}$, and $\vec s=\vec n\times\vec t$. Therefore the local coordinates of the global coordinates $X_i,Y_i$, and $Z_i$, $i=1\dots4$ can be found by the direction cosines. 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}x_i\\y_i\\ z_i\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    t_x & s_x & n_x\\
    t_y & s_y & n_y\\
    t_z & s_z & n_z\\
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_i\\Y_i\\ Z_i\\\end{bmatrix}\label{eq:G2L_TransForm},
\end{align}
where the $t_x,t_y,t_z$ are the direction cosines of the global axes $X,Y,Z$ and the local axis $t$, and the same applies for $\vec s$ and $\vec t$. 
The next we will assume that the four vertices of the quadrilateral is on the same plane, i.e., the $Z_i=z_i=0,i=1\dots4$. Let introduce two vectors $\vec m$ and $\vec n$ such that 
\begin{align}
\vec m&=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_1+\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\x_4\\ x_3\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
\vec n&=\frac{1}{2}\left(y_1+\begin{bmatrix}y_2\\y_4\\ y_3\end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align}
If the cross product of $\vec m$ and $\vec n$ is noted by $\vec l$, then the centroid $[x_c,y_c]$ of the local quadrilateral can be found
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}x_c\\y_c\\ \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{1}{3l_3}\begin{bmatrix}
    m_1 & m_2\\
    n_1 & n_2
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}l_2\\l_1\\\end{bmatrix}\label{eq:Centroid},
\end{align}
It is to prove that $l_3$ is a quarter of the quadrilateral area \begin{align}l_3&=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^4(x_iy_{i+1}-x_{i+1}y_i),
\end{align}
where $x_5=x_1$ and $y_5=y_1$.

Comment: May I know what is the reason for all that fuss? In addition: did you try your method, and does it give $(x_c,y_c)\ne(0,0)$?

Comment: In general case of quadrilaterals, $(x_c,y_c)\ne(0,0)$, but for a rectangular, the centroid will coincide with the averaged center.

Comment: The mysterious method to calculate the Centroid comes from a piece of very old code without any explanation. The above is what I formulated and tried to derive it myself, but no success reached.